# Не работает запрос в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Вот запрос...

```
select 
    vd.vendor_id, 
    vd.title, 
    vd.tax, 
    v.vtotal, 
    vs.country_id, 
    vs.zone_id, 
    c.commission
from 
    oc_vendor_discount vd, 
    oc_vendor v, 
    oc_vendors vs, 
    oc_commission 
where 
    v.vproduct_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'
and 
    vs.vendor_id = v.vendor
and 
    c.commission_id = vs.commission_id
```

Выдает синтаксических ошибку, но какую я понятия не имею, все верно! Помогите понять что за ошибка!

Ошибка ...

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  vd.vendor_id,  vd.title,  vd.tax,  v.vtotal,  vs.country_' at line 1
Error No: 1064
SELECT  vd.vendor_id,  vd.title,  vd.tax,  v.vtotal,  vs.country_id,     vs.zone_id,  c.commission FROM  oc_vendor_discount vd,  oc_vendor v,  oc_vendors vs,  oc_commission  WHERE  v.vproduct_id = '47' AND  vs.vendor_id = v.vendor AND  c.commission_id = vs.commission_id in
```

Comment: Если не сложно, дополните вопрос сообщением об ошибке.

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  vd.vendor_id,  vd.title,  vd.tax,  v.vtotal,  vs.country_' at line 1
Error No: 1064
SELECT  vd.vendor_id,  vd.title,  vd.tax,  v.vtotal,  vs.country_id,  vs.zone_id,  c.commission FROM  oc_vendor_discount vd,  oc_vendor v,  oc_vendors vs,  oc_commission  WHERE  v.vproduct_id = '47' AND  vs.vendor_id = v.vendor AND  c.commission_id = vs.commission_id in

Comment: Такое ощущение, что у вас невидимый символ перед SELECT, например, BOM от UTF-8.

Comment: Как это можно исправить? Я делаю этот запрос и в самом пхпмайадмин и тоже самое

Comment: А вы его где выполняете? В phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @privetsh, строчку `oc_commission` допишите до `oc_commission c`.

Comment: В меню Sql на сайте

Comment: Дописал. Ошибка та же

Comment: А что за `in` у вас в самом конце строчки запроса ?

Comment: Я копировал эту ошибку со страницы сайта и in там показывало в какой страке

Comment: Тогда это что то странное. я не вижу проблем в синтаксисе. Разве что спецсимвол какой нибудь незаметный затесался. Ну и лучше ошибку при наличии буквы `c` в вопрос выложите. А то может показаться что из за нее проблема

Comment: Из всего выше и нижесказанного напрашивается один вывод на мой взгляд. Попытаться воссоздать запрос по частям. Начать с одной таблицы, затем постепенно добавлять по одной. Возможно что вы просто перепишете запрос заново и будет работать (закралась русская буква). Запрос вроде бы небольшой, так что это должно помочь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
vd.vendor_id, 
vd.title, 
vd.tax, 
v.vtotal, 
vs.country_id, 
vs.zone_id, 
c.commission
from 
oc_vendor_discount vd, 
oc_vendor v, 
oc_vendors vs, 
oc_commission с <-было пропущено
where 
v.vproduct_id = '" . (int)$product['product_id'] . "'
and 
vs.vendor_id = v.vendor
and 
c.commission_id = vs.commission_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Все просто, вы пытаетесь сделать SELECT с полями: `vd.vendor_id, vd.title, vd.tax, v.vtotal, vs.country_id, vs.zone_id, c.commission`. При этом условие WHERE у вас по полям, которых нет в выборке: `v.vproduct_id, vs.vendor_id, v.vendor, c.commission_id, vs.commission_id`.

Comment: дело в другом, запрос с ошибкой!

Comment: о_О, а я о чем вам говорю. В условии WHERE были поля которых не было в SELECT. Это и есть ошибка.